# Storing data returned from ajax post- should I use async:false to store in var? Is there a better way?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
  $.post('http://localhost/test_zone/index.php/blog/new_post', { image_codes: images, info: fieldData, post_body: body },
    function(data){
     if (data.success) {
      if(data.error != ''){
        alert(data.error);
           }
      else {
        $('#preview_wrapper').css('display','none').html(data.postHTML).show(1000);
        $('#array_store').html(data.dataArray);
        }
      }
     else {
       alert('Sorry, an error occurred. No response from server.');
        }
       }

   ,'json');
```

As you can see, I'm grabbing two bits of data - postHTML & dataArray- through an ajax post function. I want to put the dataArray in a var. I've read similar questions and I beleive the solution is to use 'async: false' - causing the function to wait for the data, and insert it in the var before proceeding. So I have several questions surrounding this:

1. Firstly, how do you set 'async: false' using the shorthand jquery $.post as I am doing above, rather than $.ajax ({ type:'POST' }) ? is it possible? This would be useful to know, but I can't work it out or find an answer anywhere.
2. I've heard a lot of negative comments about using 'async: false'. Would you recommend it? If not, how can I just store some data string on the page for later use? At the moment as you can see I've set the data to be inserted into a div (set to display:none) which strikes me as being less than ideal, to say the least.
3. Why does the function not wait for the data to be inserted into a var, but when you set it to insert the data to an element on the page via .html(), it works? I guess this is like opening a door for the data string to just spill into the page in it's own time..? But why can't this methodology apply to inserting data into a var- why can't the door stay open to the var as well? (If you see what I mean!).

Apologies for a rather lengthy question- any answers or partial answers to the points above will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: here is my full code (You can probably ignore all the data gathering bits, but I'll post the lot anyway)-

```
                $('#submit').click(function(){
                    $('#input_table').hide(1000);
                    if($('.image_info').length){
                        var images = [];
                        $.each($('.image_info'), function(img_count) {
                            var img_code = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').slice(-1);
                            images.push('"' + img_count + '"' + ':' + '"' + img_code + '"');
                            img_count++;
                        });
                    images = '{' + images + '}';
                    }else {
                        var images = 'none';
                    }
                    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
                    var body = editor.getData();
                    body = clean(body);
                    var fieldData = [];
                    var cleanValue ='';                     
                    $.each($('.field'), function() {
                        cleanValue = clean($(this).val());
                        fieldData.push('"' + $(this).attr('id') + '"' + ':' + '"' + cleanValue + '"');
                    });
                    fieldData = '{' + fieldData + '}';
                    $.post('http://localhost/test_zone/index.php/blog/new_post', { image_codes: images, info: fieldData, post_body: body },
                            function(data){
                                if (data.success) {
                                    if(data.error != ''){
                                            alert(data.error);
                                                        }
                                    else {
                                            $('#preview_wrapper').css('display','none').html(data.postHTML).show(1000);
                                            $('#array_store').html(data.dataArray);
                                         }
                                    }
                                else {
                                        alert('Sorry, an error occurred. No response from server.');
                                      }
                                        }

                        ,'json');
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use async, because your browser hangs.
I have done this with events:

```
var evObj;
var _EVENT_RESULT = "resultEvent";

// Listen to the event
evObj.bind(_EVENT_RESULT, function(event, data){
  alert(data);
}

// Ajax-Request with event-triggering
$.ajax({
    type:       "POST",
    ...
    success:    function(data){
                  evObj.trigger(_EVENT_RESULT, data);
                }
});
```

The function is not waiting because its asynchronous. This is good because your code does not stop and your browser does not hang.
If you use ".html()", you insert the result into the page if the result is send back from server. It could be, that you are only "thinking" that this is working, because the result is send back very fasten. But if you server would send the result back after 10 seconds, you would have no result in your page for 10 seconds - but: you gui does not hang.

Edit: try this:

```
var evObj;
var _EVENT_RESULT = "resultEvent";

// Listen to the event
evObj.bind(_EVENT_RESULT, function(event, data){
  alert(data);
}

$('#submit').click(function(){
  ...
  else{
    ...
    $.post('http://localhost/test_zone/index.php/blog/new_post', {
      image_codes: images,
      info: fieldData,
      post_body: body },
      function(data){
        if (data.success){
          // At this point you could trigger the event
          evObj.trigger(_EVENT_RESULT, data);
        }
        else{
          alert('Sorry, an error occurred. No response from server.');
        }
        ,'json');
});
```

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about binding function- however, I can't seem to get this to work. I'm going to post my full (original) code as an edit to the original question. I tried binding the function in the first 'else' statement but I can't get it to work... perhaps you could show me how you'd implement it in my code..? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just set your vars:

```
  $.post('your_url', your_params,
     function(data){
       //Validation code here...
       window.postHTML = data.postHTML;
       window.dataArray = data.dataArray;     
  },'json');
```

Now you have access to `window.postHTML` and `window.dataArray` global vars.
For the $.post to be synchronous (I would not recommend it), you can use `$.ajaxSetup` just once:

```
$.ajaxSetup({  //This will change behavior of all subsequent ajax requests!!
  async: false
});
$.post('http://localhost/test_zone/index.ph...) //Do $.post as usual
```

Hope this helps